# Can we use custom labels to be referenced in Einstein Chatbot?

Tags: customlabel, chat, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots, chatbot

I have a use case where we are using the same URL link across multiple chatbot dialogs and we want to store it in one place and reference it in dialogs instead of putting hard text in each. It's a URL link in clickable text format that should be held in one place; so whenever we need to update it we only need to do it in one place.

I looked at multiple options:

- Custom Label - I wasn't able to much info on use of custom labels in chatbot including this website
- Enhanced Links - Could potentially work, but a picture is required to upload along with it which we don't need. I am also unable to clone a standard chatbot to enhanced due to getting errors. This seems to be a know problem https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000KgxPdSAJ
- Variables - can URL links be referenced in a clickable format